# How to add style-loader in Webpack Encore Symfony4?

Tags: webpack, symfony4

I'm using the [webpack bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html) of symfony4. Actually when I start webpack with

```
$ yarn encore dev --watch
```

The bundle (webpack bundle) generate .js files and .css files. So i need to import both the .js file and the .css file.

Now I want to only import the .js file with the .css auto provide in the .js file. I think it can be done with [style-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader). The webpack bundle provide a [function](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/custom-loaders-plugins.html) to import loader.

So here is what I wrote in `webpack.config.js`:

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    //...
    .addEntry('client', './assets/js/client/script.js')
    .addLoader({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader',
    })
    .addLoader({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'css-loader',
    })
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

In my `./assets/js/client/script.js` I have:

```
//...
require('../../css/client/style.scss');
//...
```

But when I launch webpack (`$ yarn encore dev --watch`) I have this big issue:

```
Webpack is watching the files…

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 8 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                                        9:00:53 PM

 error  in ./assets/css/client/var.scss

Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals? }
    at validate (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:34:28)
    at runLoaders (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
    at /var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at Object.context.callback (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.resolveUrlLoader (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js:132:12)

 error  in ./assets/css/client/style.scss

Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals? }
    at validate (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:34:28)
    at runLoaders (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
    at /var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at Object.context.callback (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.resolveUrlLoader (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js:132:12)

 error  in ./assets/css/app.scss

Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals? }
    at validate (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:34:28)
    at runLoaders (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
    at /var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at Object.context.callback (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.resolveUrlLoader (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js:132:12)

 error  in ./assets/css/dashboard.scss

Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals? }
    at validate (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:34:28)
    at runLoaders (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
    at /var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at Object.context.callback (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.resolveUrlLoader (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js:132:12)

 error  in ./assets/css/app.scss

Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. Style Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'sourceMap'. These properties are valid:
   object { injectType?, attributes?, insert?, base? }
    at validate (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/style-loader/dist/index.js:17:28)

 @ ./assets/js/app.js 1:0-26

 error  in ./assets/css/client/style.scss

Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. Style Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'sourceMap'. These properties are valid:
   object { injectType?, attributes?, insert?, base? }
    at validate (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/style-loader/dist/index.js:17:28)

 @ ./assets/js/client/script.js 5:0-38

 error  in ./assets/css/dashboard.scss

Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. Style Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'sourceMap'. These properties are valid:
   object { injectType?, attributes?, insert?, base? }
    at validate (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/style-loader/dist/index.js:17:28)

 @ ./assets/js/dashboard.js 1:0-32

 error  in ./assets/css/client/var.scss

Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. Style Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'sourceMap'. These properties are valid:
   object { injectType?, attributes?, insert?, base? }
    at validate (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (/var/www/chat-project-symfony/node_modules/style-loader/dist/index.js:17:28)

 @ ./assets/js/client/class/DropZoneManager.js 12:13-62
 @ ./assets/js/client/script.js
```

It seems like I didn't provide all the parameters required to load these modules but for example I have the error :

```
- options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:
```

while I cannot find this property in [style-loader doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader) neither in [css-loader doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-loader).

Here is the question:

Do you know how to configure `webpack.config.js` in symfony4 in order to compile .js and .scss file in only 1 .js file which will auto provide the compiled css?